# Nestjs Dependency Injection - Inject service into service

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I have a service which I can inject into other components without any issues.

When I try to inject that service into another service I get

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AService (?). 
Please make sure that the argument BService at index [0] is available in the AService context.
```

I cannot find any way to inject services into each other. Is this not supported, kind of an anti-pattern.... ?

And if so, how to handle a service with functionality I want to be available in all of my app in several components and services?

Code as follows:

b.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BService } from './b.service';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  exports: [bService],
  providers: [bService]
})
export class bModule { }
```

b.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class BService {
  someFunc();
}
```

a.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SensorsService } from './a.service';
import { SensorsController } from './a.controller';
import { BModule } from '../shared/b.module';

@Module({
  imports: [BModule],
  providers: [AService],
  controllers: [AController],
  exports: []
})
export class AModule { 

}
```

a.service.ts - which should be able to use b.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BService } from '../shared/b.service';

@Injectable()
export class AService {
  constructor(
    private bService: BService
  ) {}

  someOtherFunc() {}
}
```

Comment: I notice that your module in the declaration code is `bModule`, but then you're importing `BModule` - is this the issue? Same with the `bService`

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. Make sure you have the proper cases for your classes and instances. Also, would you show how these are bound to your `AppModule` if that is not the case?

Comment: @hlfrmn my modules of course have some other names. But since it started working all of the sudden after raging through the code, I would assume it was a failure like this.

Answer (score 14):

Based on your error, you have `AService` in an `imports` array somewhere, which is not something you do in NestJS. To break it down

> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AService (?).
>
> Please make sure that the argument BService at index [0] is available in the AService context.

The first part is showing the Provider that is having difficulties, along with a `?` where the unknown dependency is. In this case, `AService` is the provider that cannot be instantiated and `BService` is the unknown dependency.

The second part of the error is calling out explicitly the injection token (usually a class name) and the index in the constructor and then in what **module** context Nest is looking at. You can read that Nest says

> in the `AService` context

Meaning Nest is looking at a module called `AService`. As I said before, this is something you shouldn't do.

If you are needing the `AService` in another module, you should add the `AService` to the `AModule`'s `exports` array, and add `AModule` to the new module's `imports` array.