# call module service in another service nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I tried looking for answers on the nestjs docs and github and this question: [Nestjs Dependency Injection - Inject service into service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953178/nestjs-dependency-injection-inject-service-into-service), but couldn't find any, only a circular dependency . I have ProductService:

products.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductsService {
    constructor(@InjectModel(Product.name) private productModel: Model<ProductDocument>) {}

    // TODO: return string переделать 
    async create(createProductDto: CreateProductDto): Promise<Product> {
        // TODO: need call CategoriesService.findOne(createProductDto.id) to check exist categories by id

        const createdProduct = new this.productModel(createProductDto);

        return createdProduct.save();
    }
}
```

in products.module.ts i and add to imports array categories module

products.module.ts

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forFeature([
            { name: Product.name, schema: ProductSchema },
        ]),
        // add CategoriesModule
        CategoriesModule,
    ],
    controllers: [ProductController],
    providers: [ProductsService],
})
export class ProductModule {}
```

categories.module.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class CategoriesService {
    constructor(@InjectModel(Category.name) private categoryModel: Model<CategoryDocument>) {}
    async findOne(@Param('id') id: string): Promise<boolean> {
        // need only check exist category
        const exist = await this.categoryModel.findOne({ id }, { _id: true });
        if (exist) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to correctly call the service methods of another module

Answer (score 0):

in products.service.ts i add private variable categoriesService, and just call this

```
constructor(@InjectModel(Product.name) private productModel: Model<ProductDocument>, private readonly categoriesService: CategoriesService) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your categories service from within the Categories module

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.